# Is there a correct way to connect the AC charger to a laptop?

Tags: battery, charging

I want to know if there is a correct way attach the AC charger to charge a laptop's battery.

1. Should I plug in the charger to the power source and then to the laptop? or...
2. Should I plug in the charger first to the laptop and then to the power source?

Answer (score 0):

That's one question I always asked myself but didn't have the courage / didn't bother to ask.

Thinking a bit here, I would say it is better to plug it first on the power source, and then plug to the laptop.

Why is that: the chargers do not output the nominal voltage as soon as it is plugged. Some ramp up voltage gradually, some do crazy voltage spike before stabilizing, etc.. If you are using the genuine adapter that came with the laptop, you're safe either way because the laptop hardware is spec-ed accordingly to it, so it is built to withstand these voltage instabilities. But if you're not using the original adapter, than it is better to be safe.

Comment: But you are safe either way (i.e. with the original adapter or with some other) by first connecting to the power source right?

Comment: @TomWilson yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing it the opposite way all the time jeje